# Calculation of Vce from Ic-Vge Characteristic

Tags: power-electronics, semiconductors, igbt, powermosfet

We have found the Ic-Vge (collector current vs gate-emitter voltage) characteristic of an IGBT device as shown below at a high Vce (collector-emitter voltage) value (here 20V) from the datasheet (related to the IGBT device with the part number IFS75B12N3E4_B31).
However, I want to study on normal conditions where Vce is less than 4V. 
Can we extend the Ic-Vge characteristic from such a high Vce voltage to a low one?

[image]

Comment: I've read this a couple of times but unfortunately I still don't understand what your question is. Maybe you can try to rephrase it?

Comment: Are you asking what the graph would look like for lower values of Ic and Vce?

Comment: @divB sorry, it is rephrased.

Comment: @Annie yes, I want to find an Ic-Vce graph for lower values of Ic and Vce. The text is rephrased.

Comment: @Annie Could you please give me a relationship for Ic in terms of Vce and Vbe?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that using this graph from the same datasheet:
[image]

For the value of Vce that you are interested in, you have six points (one for each Vge value). From that, you can form an idea of the full curve.

Comment: Could you please give me a relationship for Ic in terms of Vce and Vbe?

Comment: @Mohsen The graph I've described will give you an approximation of the relationship. That's as close as I can get.